# Powershell - Removing all duplicate entries

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to find a Powershell command line that will read in a text file remove all duplicated lines (2+) and retain none of the duplicated lines. I haven't been able to find an answer for my question anywhere on Stackoverflow nor anywhere else.  Every example I have found so far only shows removing one and/or many of the duplicated lines and retaining one.

Is this possible through Powershell 2.0?

**PowerShell Command Example:**

```
Get-Content "C:\Temp\OriginalFile.txt" | select  -unique| Out-File "C:\Temp\ResultFile.txt"
```

**OriginalFile.txt**

```
1
1
1
2
2
3
4
```

**ResultFile.txt (Actual)**

```
1
2
3
4
```

**ResultsFile.txt (Desired)**

```
3
4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PSv2:

```
$f = 'C:\Temp\OriginalFile.txt'

Get-Content $f | Group-Object | ? { $_.Count -eq 1 } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

PSv3+ allows for a cleaner and more concise solution:

```
Get-Content $f | Group-Object | ? Count -eq 1 | % Name
```

<sup>For brevity, the commands use built-in aliases `?` (for `Where-Object`) and `%` (for `ForEach-Object`).</sup>

Neither `Select-Object -Unique` nor `Get-Unique` seemingly allow restricting the output to singletons in the input (standard Unix utility `uniq` has such a feature built in: `uniq -u`), so a different approach is needed.

The above `Group-Object`-based solution may not be efficient, but it is convenient:

- lines are grouped by identical content, yielding objects that represent each group.
- `? { $_.Count -eq 1 }` the filters the groups down to those that have just 1 member, in effect weeding out all duplicate lines.
- `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` then transforms the filtered group objects back to the input line they represent.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I got this working due to your response.

Comment: I did have to modify `Select-Object -Expand Name` to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`

Comment: @packetloss: Good point: the full parameter name is `-ExpandProperty`, and in scripts one should definitely use the full parameter names (although `-Expand` would have worked too) - answer updated.