# Removing all duplicate entries in a CSV

Tags: powershell, duplicates

I have a question similar to this one:

[Powershell - Removing all duplicate entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833926/powershell-removing-all-duplicate-entries/58536798?noredirect=1#comment103397440_58536798)

But is there a way to handle this when there are more columns, like this:

1 Berlin Germany 
1 Frankfurt Germany 
1 Munich Germany 
2 London England 
3 Washington USA 
3 Seattle USA 
 
4 Vienna Austria

Only the first column should be used to determine if there are duplicates. If duplicates are found the whole line should be removed.

So the expected result, in this case, would be:

2 London England 
4 Vienna Austria

(as only number 2 and 4 appear only once in the CSV)

```
#First I load a csv.
$Liste = import-csv -path $Eingabedatei -delimiter ','
```

It only contains the columns mentioned above. The first column is called 'EintragNr'.

I tried like this (using the Code from the mentioned example as Basis)

```
$Liste | Format-Table | Group-Object EintragNr | ? Count -eq 1 | % Name
```

but I get no result.  I am using the `Format-table` because in the Output I need to have all the columns that are contained in the line.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: First of all, formatting of content should always be done last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't nee the Format-Table, try this:

```
$Liste | Group-Object EintragNr | ? Count -eq 1 | % {$_.Group[0]}
```